# I am a bit confused about relative measurement

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to CSS. I received a lecture on Text Styling (relative unit and absolute). And in the lecture, it was specified in the body tag that the font-size be 120% as the lecturer said most browsers default font-size is 16px (absolute unit).
He went ahead and apply an in-line styling to override the previous declaration, but made use of the “em” unit.
He explained:
2em = 240% = 38px  (twice large as the parent element)
0.5em=50%...
I tried what I understood to make a two-column layout…Inserted 2 paragraphs inside a div and floated them left. I made their width 50% of the viewport –it worked fine.
Then I decided to replace the 50% by 0.5em which I think it should be half of the parent element(the div) since a div is 100% by default. I was surprised by the result…
 I really don’t understand anymore!

Here is my code:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  margin-bottom: 10px;


}

p {
  width: 50%; /* worked fine */
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: .5em; 
  margin-top: 0em;  

  /* when the p width was 50%, as i scaled the browser everything adjusted...but with 18em it doesn't */
  margin-top: 0%

}

#p1 {
  background-color: #A52A2A;



}
#p2 {
  background-color: #DEB887;
  float: left;

}

section {
  clear: both;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Two Column Design</h1>

<div>
  <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia distinctio aliquid cupiditate perferendis fuga, sit quasi alias vero sunt non, ratione earum dolores nihil! Consequuntur pariatur totam incidunt soluta expedita.</p>
  <p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta beatae voluptatibus veniam placeat iure unde assumenda porro neque voluptate esse sit magnam facilis labore odit, provident a ea! Nulla, minima.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius nemo vitae, cupiditate odio magnam reprehenderit esse eum reiciendis repellendus incidunt sequi! Autem, laudantium, accusamus. Doloribus tempora alias minima laborum, provident!</p>
  <section>This is regular content continuing after the the paragraph boxes.</section>
</div>
```

Comment: `em` is a unit of measurement that basically tells the browser (in the example you have provided) - "hey, make this element be the same width as its default font size". So when you tell your browser make this 0.5em and the element's default font-size is 16px, you're telling that element to be 8px wide (setting padding for the element can make it take up more space).

Comment: Thank you, TKD21. But you are  saying em only works with font size, right?

Comment: `em` is a **relative measurement unit** which means that it specifies a length based on something else that is already defined in the HTML page. So yes, it is absolutely tied to an element's font-size. Maybe [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) can provide more details for you?

Comment: Thank you very much. i am cleared